# UWP SpeechRecognizer Pause Limit Exceeded

Tags: c#, uwp, speech-recognition, windows-10-iot-core

I have developed a UWP application running on Windows 10 IoT Core, version 15063. Whenever the application runs and I start the continuous speech recognition session, shortly after I get the "Pause Limit Exceeded" message.

I need to know where this limit is set, can someone please help me? All the source code is up here - https://github.com/IEvangelist/mirror.

Comment: Maybe [AutoStopSilenceTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechcontinuousrecognitionsession#properties_)?

Comment: What's your IoT Core device?

Comment: @AVK nope, tried that first. Rita, I am using a Raspberry Pi 3.